# MySQL delete row from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row, sql-delete

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3, t4 FROM 
  table1 as t1 
  INNER JOIN  table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  INNER JOIN  table3 as t3 on t1.id=t3.id
  INNER JOIN  table4 as t4 on t1.id=t4.id
  WHERE  t1.username='%s' AND t1.id='%s'
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to delete a row from multiple tables where each row shares a common ID.. is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am trying to do . sorry for not adding that in the description

Comment: Well have you run it? Either do this and ask when it does not work or check the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: I did ..it deleted only the entry from table 4

Comment: Are you just trying to do a cascading delete for a normalized db?

Comment: Maybe you should put your problem into the question.

Comment: Why do you need to test both the username and the id in your where clause? Is the id not unique?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. It works fine here:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, username nvarchar(30));
CREATE TABLE table2 (id int);
CREATE TABLE table3 (id int);
CREATE TABLE table4 (id int);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'Foo'),(2, 'Bar');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1),(2);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (1),(2);
INSERT INTO table4 VALUES (1),(2);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;
2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2;
2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3;
2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4;
2

DELETE t1, t2, t3, t4 FROM
  table1 as t1
  INNER JOIN  table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
  INNER JOIN  table3 as t3 on t1.id=t3.id
  INNER JOIN  table4 as t4 on t1.id=t4.id
  WHERE  t1.username='Foo' AND t1.id='1';

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1;
1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2;
1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table3;
1
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table4;
1
```

If it's not working for you, perhaps you can modify this example to show what problem you are having.

Comment: Is there a difference between what you posted ( i tried) and the answer posted above? 
:"
Delete From table1 as t1 
        INNER JOIN  table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        INNER JOIN  table3 as t3 on t1.id=t3.id
        INNER JOIN  table4 as t4 on t1.id=t4.id
        WHERE  t1.username='%s' AND t1.id='%s' "
-
if so, which one is better? thank you

Comment: @salmane: Yeah, the main difference is that other answer doesn't work at all (try it - it gives a syntax error). He's changed it now though.

Comment: The real way to say thank you is to mark this question as answered and giving credit to Mark.

Comment: This only works if `id = 1` exists in _all four_ tables. If you wish to delete the row from any table that _might_ have a `id = 1`, then you cannot accomplish that via a single delete statement.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to figure it out is to first write it as a query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
        table1 as t1 
        INNER JOIN  table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        INNER JOIN  table3 as t3 on t1.id=t3.id
        INNER JOIN  table4 as t4 on t1.id=t4.id
        WHERE  t1.username='%s' AND t1.id='%s'
```

If you get the results you expect, just replace the *Select ** with Delete and your table names.  Then it would become:

```
Delete t1, t2, t3, t4 From table1 as t1 
        INNER JOIN  table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
        INNER JOIN  table3 as t3 on t1.id=t3.id
        INNER JOIN  table4 as t4 on t1.id=t4.id
        WHERE  t1.username='%s' AND t1.id='%s'
```

Answer (score 2):

Make it simple with:

```
DELETE FROM `Table1` t1, `Table2` t2 USING t1, t2
WHERE t1.`id` =  t2.`id` AND t1.`id` = 10; <br>
```

Enjoy :)