# Android SQL Insert, Add, Delete etc. to Multiple Tables Within One Statement?

Tags: android, sql

Is it possible to example use:

```
String sql = "DELETE field FROM table1, table2 WHERE field='x', field='y'";
```

To delete multiple fields from multiple tables? I ask because I am using creating a clean up method that will go through and delete all references to an object in all of my database tables when I delete that object and it seems easier to add everything into one sql statement as opposed to building a separate sql for each table and then executing each one individually. If one statement isn't possible is there another solutions? Such as building an sql array perhaps and then executing all with one command?

Comment: Don't know which DBMS that is on Android, but `DELETE field FROM` is an invalid (standard) SQL statement. `DELETE` does not work on column level, it works on row level.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The standard is, AFAIK, SQLite for both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. You need to do multiple delete statements, one per table.

Comment: I kinda figured that much, but just thought i'd check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many databases allow for several statements to be in one string separated by `;` and then executed in one command.

e.g.

```
String sql = 
         "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE field='x' and field='y'; 
          DELETE FROM table2 WHERE field='x' and field='y';";

 Command.Commandtext = sql;
 Command.Execute();
```

However I do not have specific knowledge about Android so if I'm wrong let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to delete the field or the entire row?  If row then yes you can do the delete in all the tables, if they have Foreign Keys.

Take a look at this post [MySQL delete row from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214433/mysql-delete-row-from-multiple-tables)

That should give you the clue and good luck...