# rawquery() issue

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using rawquery() for perform inner join, but this is not giving me any error and does not working, if i use this query directly into sqlite browser than this is working but in application this query does not work, following is my code, sorry for bad English communication

```
public void deleteFifo() {
    final String MY_QUERY1 = "Delete from Items where res_id in (select _id from Favourite where _id not in (select _id from Favourite order by date desc limit 50))";
    final String MY_QUERY2 = "Delete from Favourite where _id not in (select _id from Favourite order by date desc limit 50)";
    db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY1, null);
    db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY2, null);
}
```

Comment: use SubQuery or Join Query...

Comment: please come into chatgroup sai_group_chat.

Comment: try this , Hop it may help you..

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214433/mysql-delete-row-from-multiple-tables][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214433/mysql-delete-row-from-multiple-tables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886455/android-sql-insert-add-delete-etc-to-multiple-tables-within-one-statement

Comment: Try `execSQL()` RawQuery is for Queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
db.delete(TableName, whereCondition, null);
```

i.e. in your case

```
db.delete("Items", "res_id in (select _id from Favourite where 
_id not in (select _id from Favourite order by date desc limit 50))", null);
```

and

```
db.delete("Favourite ","_id not in (select _id from Favourite 
order by date desc limit 50)");
```

Hope it helps !!