# Delete everything about an user from all tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL delete row from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214433/mysql-delete-row-from-multiple-tables)

I have 5 tables:

- members
- member_videos
- member_photos
- member_friends
- member_pages

When I delete that member, I want to delete all his records from these tables. `member_id` exist in all tables. I'm doing this with 5 queries for each table. Can I use `LEFT JOIN` or something like this do to this in one query?

Comment: Be verrry, verry careful performing mass-DELETE operations. There's no Ctrl+Z for your MySQL database :)

Comment: You *can* (see [Multiple-table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)), but the better question is, should you?

Comment: @JaredFarrish you should post as an answer I'd vote it up.

Comment: A simple research such as "multiple table delete" would have given you the answer ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
DELETE m, mv, mp, mf, mpp
FROM members AS m
LEFT JOIN member_videos  AS mv  ON mv.member_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN member_photos  AS mp  ON mp.member_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN member_friends AS mf  ON mf.member_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN member_pages   AS mpp ON mpp.member_id = m.id
WHERE m.id = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Check this page, there is a section for multiple-tables DELETE.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can. However, I think you can separate the queries with ; and give it as one query to mysql_query() or whatever you're using. For example:

```
mysql_query('DELETE * FROM members WHERE user_id = 4; DELETE * FROM member_videos WHERE user_id = 4;');
```

and so on :)

Comment: You want to delete the contents of the `members` table LAST, because of foreign key contraints.

Comment: I just showed an example, but thanks for the correction :)

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking (multiple statements in one request); it's one query, period. And you can, just [refer to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).