# Codeigniter delete query not working

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

I need to delete records from three tables at a time.Here is my query:-

```
$query =$this->db->query("DELETE ps_faq_categories FROM ps_faq_categories INNER JOIN ps_faqs ON('ps_faq_categories.faq_category_id = ps_faqs.faq_category_id') 
                     INNER JOIN ps_faq_comments ON('ps_faqs.faq_id = ps_faq_comments.faq_id') WHERE 'ps_faq_categories.faq_category_id' = $category_id");
```

I am getting error like , An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'INNER'.

Answer (score 0):

remove single quote from the query

```
$query =$this->db->query("DELETE ps_faq_categories,ps_faqs,ps_faq_comments FROM ps_faq_categories INNER JOIN ps_faqs ON(ps_faq_categories.faq_category_id = ps_faqs.faq_category_id) 
                     INNER JOIN ps_faq_comments ON(ps_faqs.faq_id = ps_faq_comments.faq_id) WHERE ps_faq_categories.faq_category_id = $category_id");
```

Comment: I have tried this , but havent solved am getting error, Incorrect syntax near '`'

Comment: The record deleted from ps_faq_categories but not deleting from ps_faqs and ps_faq_comments.Is their any problem in my query

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work , [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: the multi-part identifier "ps_faq_categories.faq_category_id" could not be bound.

Comment: i updated the query and check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214433/mysql-delete-row-from-multiple-tables it will may be help you