# Delete record where from multi table when it doesn't exist in table

Tags: sql, command

I have 3 tables.

- `mainT` has primary key `main_id`
- `sub1T` has foreign key to `main_id`
- `sub2T` has foreign key to `main_id`

I need to delete all records from `sub1T` and `sub2T` in one SQL command.

I know how to delete all records inside sub1T using this command:

```
DELETE FROM `sub1T` 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                  FROM mainT 
                  WHERE `mainT`.main_id = main_id)
```

I need to delete from multiple child tables

Comment: I don't think you can delete from multiple tables in one command. You need to write PL/SQL for that.

Comment: Most RDBMS support `on delete cascade`, which will delete data from child tables, when parent is deleted. For current requirement, you should use `2` `delete` statements and then try to implement `on delete cascade` on current table structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL delete row from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214433/mysql-delete-row-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: we cant do this in simple sql command